# Why won't my child div stay inside the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with a child div but the child div is displaying under the parent div when it is inside the parent.

I have tried `z-index` but to no avail it did nothing.

I just would like the dots to be inside and on top of the parent. But instead they are under it.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a img {
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.nav-first {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.mobile-button,
.mobile-navbar-text,
.closebtn,
.media-links {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slideshow {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
}

.slideshow img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.dot {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.dot:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>U.S.A Plates</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/american-flag-logo-vector.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-first navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <span class="mobile-button">&#9776;</span>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="mobile-sidenavbar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <div class="media-links">
      <a href="#" class="fa facebook">&#xf082;</a>
      <a href="#" class="fa twitter">&#xf081;</a>
      <a href="#" class="fa instagram">&#xf16d;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow">
    <img name="slide" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554457604-71bd155ff013?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3648&q=80" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="masterjs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The dots ARE inside the parent div. Do you mean you want them to be in the nav?

Comment: Your 100% tall image pushes it under. Use `<img name="slide" alt="" width="100%" height="90%">` to see the dots inside and on top

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Oh, I forgot to check in Chrome; sorry. The problem isn't there in Firefox. My bad. @mplugjan is right.

Comment: I see what you mean with the height 90% that does push it into the div. Except thats not what I want. I know its not 100% for you guys but for me there is an image that takes up 100% of the height and width of the parent div as the background. That is why it pushes the dots down under it but i would like it to be on top of the image.

Comment: I added an image instead to better show what the main issue is. The dots are in the div yes but not on top of the image itself.

Comment: Then you need to make the div with the dots position absolute

Comment: I have tried ```position: absolute``` but it just overlaps the dots on top of each other.

Comment: container: 
`#dots {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0; 
  margin-left:48%
}` - someone else can show you how to center them, I forget why margin:auto does not work

Comment: Because you haven't given them different locations on the screen. A better approach would be to make the div they're in (`<div style="text-align:center;">`) position:absolute.

Comment: Wait, wait. The image is supposed to be the background, right? Then why don't you make it into a background css property rather than an <img>? Then you can dispense with teh position:absolute.

Comment: @MrLister Well its because I have it as a carousel. In the JS the code swaps through several images every 7 seconds and I am using the ```<img>``` tag so its more like the image is being placed there rather than being the background.

Comment: Add an id tag (I used #test) to the `<div style="text-align:center;">` above the dots and then add `#test{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 47%;
  margin-top: -30px;
}` to your CSS. Check out a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L5xo7e82/4/

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that you are setting `CSS` properties for a background image, though you're using a static `img`. Instead of `background-size: cover`, use `object-fit: cover`.

As for the dots, you can position them absolutely and pin them to the bottom of the `.slideshow` container. Using transform, you can position them directly in the center of the container. I added a `class` around the `span` containing your `.dot` children and added these described styles to it.

```css
.dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[image]

```css
body,
html {
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a img {
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.nav-first {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.mobile-button,
.mobile-navbar-text,
.closebtn,
.media-links {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slideshow {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
}

.slideshow img {
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}

.dot {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.dot:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>U.S.A Plates</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/american-flag-logo-vector.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-first navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-text">Sample Text</a></li>
      <span class="mobile-button">&#9776;</span>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="mobile-sidenavbar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <a href="#" class="mobile-navbar-text">Sample Text</a>
    <div class="media-links">
      <a href="#" class="fa facebook">&#xf082;</a>
      <a href="#" class="fa twitter">&#xf081;</a>
      <a href="#" class="fa instagram">&#xf16d;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow">
    <img name="slide" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554457604-71bd155ff013?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3648&q=80" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
    <div class="dots">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="masterjs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did what you said it work tremendously thank you! Except when I ```object-fit: cover``` it looks good when I am using google chromes device tester but when I exit it and view it without the console open it seems very zoomed/stretched why is that happening?

Comment: @Cody It's scaling to cover the `100%` width set in the parent. Is there a maximum width you'd to have for the total width of the image?

Comment: The images are quite large so that that issue wouldn't arise but no matter the size of the image it still zooms in/stretches. The max width would just to be 100% because i need it to fit 100% no matter the device size.

Comment: So only specify one direction

Comment: I think it is that the images are actually too small. The width is smaller than i thought. EDIT: Actually I am wrong again. I checked and my one image has a width of 5608px so i do not see why it is doing.